# Saving shp polygon from Google Earth

Tags: shapefile, polygon, google-earth, save

I have made a polygon in Google Earth, but somehow there is no icon or feature for saving .shp. Is there any way to save a shapefile in Google Earth?

[image]

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 9):

There is no export to shapefile via Google Earth.

These steps when using the Google Earth web version:

Once you are in the project section, you can click on the three vertical dots and then export as KML file as mentioned on this thread

[image]

These steps when using Earth Pro desktop version:

You will need to right-click the polygon layer, then click on Save As and select KML. Which you can then view in a GIS application/service. If needed, you can find a tool to convert your KML to shapefile.

[image]

[image]

Comment: QGIS will be able to view the exported kml and 'save as' shapefile  https://qgis.org/en/site/

Answer (score 0):

whyzar is right that Google Earth does not have a way to save to a shapefile, but can save to a KML which can then be converted to a shapefile with other software. Since it looks like you're using the new web version of Google Earth (not the Earth Pro desktop version), the UI is a bit different than described. You'll want to use the 3-dot menu at the top of your project panel, where you should find an option to save as KML.